# 2GP packages in Salesforce production?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am setting up a saleforce DX project that needs me to enable 2GP. I am just curious if there are any drawbacks of enabling it? I read that there is no going back so I just want to make sure its worth it. I also want to know if anyone knows of any drawbacks of enabling expanded source tracking?

Comment: No realistic drawbacks. You don't have to use it even if enabled, and it doesn't stop you using legacy packaging options either.